# Passing multiple varibles to a script for SQL query

Tags: shell-script, ksh, sql

I have this script called info_code:

```
#!/bin/ksh

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ;then
  echo "Enter code : \c"
  read code
  echo ""
else
  code=$1
fi

code=`echo ${code} | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`

echo "select * from table 
where request_no=|$code|
```

When I run info_code I have to put the request's code in the end as a variable.
I'd like to insert more than one code per time.
The column request_no is a varchar.

Comment: How do you want them to be printed? `|foo bar baz|`? `foo|bar|baz`? Something else? Please [edit] your question and provide example output. Also, do you need to provide the ability to enter multiple codes manually or is it enough to pass them as arguments?

Comment: This script make a query to a DB and the output is a normal response sql.

Comment: Perhaps, but I don't really know SQL. I do know shell scripting and would be able to help if you would just show the output you want. Remember that this is a *nix site, not a DB administrators one.

Comment: I do know. In fact my problem is with the script, not with the SQL code.
I'd like to know how to pass more than one variable to the SQL code.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like:

```
#!/bin/ksh
typeset -Au codes
read -rA codes?"Enter codes: "
IFS=,
sql="select * from table where request_no in (${codes[*]})"
echo "$sql"
```

Running that looks like:

```
Enter codes: foo bar baz
select * from table where request_no in (FOO,BAR,BAZ)
```

Proper quoting of values left as an exercise.

Comment: Yes, 
Look exactly what i need.
I've tried but i got this error:
`./getver[3]: typeset: bad option(s)`

To be clear, i'd like to keep the loop to check the value in input and just to let you know the value in input are varchar, so in the select, every single value, should between quote.